# "Double" as adjective: is it attributive-only, never predicative?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is this sentence correct:

*The semantics of ... is double.*

There is an opionion "double" cannot be an adjective in such position, and a related compound must be used:

- *The semantics of ... is double-edged.* (or double-fledged, double-fold, etc.)

But I have found a counterexample written by a literary critic:

> - *Melville's achievement was double: he brought myth into ...*

So may "double" as an adjective be used predicatively?

Comment: There are many, *many* written instances of, for example, [*the purpose was double*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22purpose+was+double%22) in Google Books. I don't believe there's *an opionion "double" cannot be an adjective in such position* (nor is there any such ***opinion*** :). It just so happens that *idiomatically*, "predicative" use of ***double*** is / has become relatively uncommon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find authoritative endorsement here, but I'll give a reasoned answer.

(1) As an adjective, 'double' is usually used attributively. I can't find an example sentence in a dictionary where it is used predicatively.

(2) One can readily find well-written examples on the internet of the form

> - *Prescription Drug Benefit: If a person chooses to buy two policies, the benefits are double.*

However, all these seem to be reductions of

- ... the benefits are double (= twice) what they would otherwise be.

(3) I'd say that 'Melville's achievement was double (= twofold)' is at best unusual.
Here, supporting evidence (not proof) *is* available, from [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benefits+are+twofold%2Cbenefits+are+double&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbenefits%20are%20twofold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbenefits%20are%20double%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

[About half the hits for 'benefits are double' are false-positives, with strings like 'the benefits are double the pre-modernisation ones' or compounds like 'the benefits are double-edged'.]

Comment: It is very interesting though to see that attributively, **double benefits** is preferred to **twofold benefits**. I find this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benefits+are+double%2Cbenefits+are+twofold%2Cdouble+benefits%2Ctwofold+benefits&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) even more revelatory.

Comment: **Twofold** and **double** are not synonyms: "With the first scheme, the benefits are twofold - you get £60,000 and life insurance; with the second scheme the cash benefits are double - you get £120,000 cash instead of £60,000 - but there is no life insurance.

Comment: @Greybeard Oh, but there are instances when "double" and "twofold" are [synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/double.html).

Comment: OP's example certainly uses 'double' in place of 'twofold', and there are other examples, as I say.

Comment: Wouldn't you just say "benefits double" making it a verb?

Comment: I'd use 'doubly' there. But 'The benefits are twofold [: ...]' adds a nice gravitas.